Should we have tags for specific disorders / conditions, or keep tags more general?
I asked a question about a specific condition, and on chat my choice of tags was brought up by Artem Kaznatcheev:

I don't think we need a whole new tag for 'prosopagnosia'
It is a single disorder, do we need a tag for every single disorder?

So, to blatantly rip off Artem's question: Should we have tags for specific disorders / conditions, or keep tags more general?

I am in favor of having specific tags for every single disorder:

This will allow us to organize our questions better
This gives users the ability to mark disorders they have specific knowledge of as favorites
This gives users the ability to ignore specific disorders
This gives each disorder / condition it's own RSS feed
This gives us stats on which disorders / conditions receive the most questions / answers over time
This allows us to have a tag wiki for each disorder


I don't see any reason why not really

@BenBrocka One reason I can think of is if we don't have multiple questions with the tag applied the tags will be removed automatically by the system at some point. Always make sure other suitable tags are applied as well.

@StevenJeuris that's just a natural part of the system. Tag what's important, and if it turns out there really aren't ever any other questions about that topic, they're removed. There's no reason tagging the relevant disorder(s) should prevent normal tagging
